# vue.esm.js:578 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "id"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use the dynamic route in the detail component:

```
dataCenterDetail: '/data-center/detail/:id'
```

in the component there is a props with `id`:

```
export default{
    props: {
      id:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    },
```

when I push to the detail route: 
in the browser: `http://localhost:8080/data-center/detail/1`

I will get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "id"

found in

---> <WxNumberDetail> at src/views/数据中心/wx-number-detail.vue
       <Index> at src/views/index.vue
         <App> at src/app.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `props: true` to you route definution

```
 { path: 'center/detail/:id', component: MyComp, props: true }
```

See [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `router.params` to receive it:

```
this.$router.params.id
```

to receive the passed id.

If you want to use `props` to receive, you should config like this:

```
{ path: 'center/detail/:id', component: dataCenterDetailComponent, props: true }
```